# Bootstrap 4.3.1 accordian second item does not expand

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I have recently upgraded from bootstrap 4.1.1 to 4.3.1 and found the accordian is broken and the second card does not expand when clicked.

Here is Jsfiddle link - https://jsfiddle.net/brvaland/k9pcL543/

```
<div class="accordion" id="accordion">
    <div class="card">
        <div class="card-header" id="h-ca92c66d-4f5e-723d-0292-fc40631afe00">
            <h5 class="mb-0">
                <a href="#ca92c66d-4f5e-723d-0292-fc40631afe00" class="btn btn-block" data-toggle="collapse"
                    data-target="#ca92c66d-4f5e-723d-0292-fc40631afe00" aria-expanded="true"
                    aria-controls="ca92c66d-4f5e-723d-0292-fc40631afe00">Collapse Group Item #1</a>
            </h5>
        </div>
        <div id="ca92c66d-4f5e-723d-0292-fc40631afe00" class="collapse show"
            aria-labelledby="h-ca92c66d-4f5e-723d-0292-fc40631afe00" data-parent="#accordion" style="">
            <div class="card-body">


                <div class="rte">
                    Group #1 Content
                </div>


            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="card">
        <div class="card-header" id="h-5158f2f7-8663-7094-45db-717071540cdb">
            <h5 class="mb-0">
                <a href="#5158f2f7-8663-7094-45db-717071540cdb" class="btn btn-block collapsed" data-toggle="collapse"
                    data-target="#5158f2f7-8663-7094-45db-717071540cdb" aria-expanded="false"
                    aria-controls="5158f2f7-8663-7094-45db-717071540cdb">Collapse Group Item #2</a>
            </h5>
        </div>
        <div id="5158f2f7-8663-7094-45db-717071540cdb" class="collapse"
            aria-labelledby="h-5158f2f7-8663-7094-45db-717071540cdb" data-parent="#accordion">
            <div class="card-body">


                <div class="rte">
                    Group #1 Content
                </div>


            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

One thing i noticed is that if i change guid to collapseOne and collapseTwo it starts working but i don't why guid is having an issue. With bootstrap 4.1.0 it was working fine.

Comment: You can't have an id that starts with a number, that is not valid html.  You must prefix your GUID with an alpha character `i-` for instance. https://jsfiddle.net/dost6vbn/

Comment: Thanks. Why bootstrap 4.1.1 worked fine ?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/brvaland/k9pcL543/1/ - v4.1 works here

Comment: I don’t know why 4.1.1 worked fine but your html was not correct regardless of what version was being used. You can’t have ids that start with numbers.

Comment: No worries, it works now